# In Win2d canvasControl , how to call createResources event multiple times whenever needed?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I have a canvasControl,in that CreateResources Event is fired only once when I run the Program.I had a FilePicker to pick an image source from local.Whenever an Image is Picked , i need to Call CreateResources event to load the Resources and then draw it using canvasBitmap and DrawingSession.
I Know how to Draw but,I Don't Know how to Load Resources Whenever an image is picked.Can anyone Suggest me ,how to achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Win2D, the `CreateResource` event is only triggered when the `CanvasControl` is loading, that is, it will only be triggered once.

If you need to create resources after this, you need to create a custom `LoadResourcesForLevelAsync` method:

```cs
async Task LoadResourcesForLevelAsync(CanvasControl resourceCreator, int level)
{
    levelBackground = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(resourceCreator, ...);
    levelThingie = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(resourceCreator, ...);
    // etc.
}
```

This is explained in the Win2D documentation, please refer to this document:

- [Loading resources outside of CreateResources](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/LoadingResourcesOutsideCreateResources.htm)

---

**Update**

A simple example of loading pictures in the `Draw` event:

```cs
private string imageFilePath = @"ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png";
private CanvasBitmap img;

private void CanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    if (img != null)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(img);
    }
    else
    {
        GetImage().Wait();
    }
    async Task GetImage()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            img = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, new Uri(imageFilePath));
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: yeah,i had refer that win2d Documentation,I can't understand what they are trying to say..can u explain it briefly?

Comment: how can I use it to my case?

Comment: Hello, I updated my answer. Also, as Muzib said, the `CreateResources` event will only run once.

Comment: here u didn't use LoadResourcesForLevelAsync() and createresources event ??why??

Comment: I omitted the code of the `CreateResources` event, because the event can only be triggered once, so the real solution is how to create resources outside the `CreateResources` event.  
The example given by the official may be a little complicated, and calling `Wait()` directly in the UI thread may cause a deadlock, so I gave a simple example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: ok..its working fine.But i need to know how the official solution works.Can you explain it?

Comment: It is essentially the same as the example I provided. The most critical code is `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync()`. The example on the official website looks complicated, but it considers some situations in actual use (including the level of rendering and the rendering before interruption). You need to decide whether to use it according to your actual situation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to load resources in `CreateResource` event all the time, you can load resources whenever you want (outside of `Draw` event handler) and then just call `Invalidate` method. Look at this:

```
CanvasBitmap btmp;
private async void LoadNecessaryResourcesAndDraw()
{
    btmp = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(MyCanvasControl, "some_image.png");
    MyCanvasControl.Invalidate(); /// this will invoke the draw event
}

public void MyCanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    if(btmp != null)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(btmp);
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `LoadNecessaryResourcesAndDraw()` method anytime. It will load the image asynchronously, then invoke the draw event which will draw the image.

Comment: its working ,but i want to use  createResources event ?

Comment: the `CreateResource` event is designed to be used once only, you can't manually invoke it.